# How can we prepare chart for Azure DevOps orgnization

Tags: azure-devops

I have one Azure DevOps organisation and under that organisation lot of work is happening like adding project, adding users, giving different-different access level to users.

I want to prepare a report and chart which will show how many project got added in given time frame, how many users got access, what kind of access has been given to each users etc.

Can anybody suggest how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use REST api to generate your own report.

- [Projects - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1): Get all projects in the organization that the authenticated user has access to.

  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1`
- [User Entitlements - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1): Get a paged set of user entitlements.

  `GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview.1`

Comment: Have you checked the API? Is it helpful?